# How can I add a Custom Experience Button for a Link List Item (section)

Tags: sxa

I have cloned a link list rendering.  Whilst I can attach a custom experience button for the experience editing to my cloned rendering - it's actually the item properties that I need to facilitate editing of.  Is there a way to attach a custom experience button to here?

[image]

Or do I need to somehow specify the fields for editing differently against the actual custom button?

[image]

My template looks like this:

[image]

Some properties are used as attributes and hence not displayed in a way the editor could edit them from experience editor.  eg: Content Position and Icon colour which are droplinks.

ie. my rendering data source is the link list with icons, which has child link items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Buttons which you see in the Link edit frame are defined in the Core database. Take a look here:

[image]

Now investigate `Link List.cshtml` and take a look at the edit frame which is defined there:

```
@using (Html.Sxa().BeginEditFrame(item.ID.ToString(), "Link", Model.IsControlEditable))
{
    foreach (BaseVariantField variantField in Model.VariantFields)
    {
        @Html.RenderingVariants().RenderVariant(variantField, item, Model.RenderingWebEditingParams, Model)
    }
}
```

The second parameter of the `BegineEditFrame()` method defines a set of buttons (it is a name of the item I've shown in the first picture) which will be displayed in the edit frame.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation!  Do you think by adding a button to this section there's a danger on upgrading that it would get deleted? (either upgrade of sitecore or sxa).

Comment: If you want to be 100% sure that nothing will be lost than clone this rendering and modify your own edit frame buttons.

Comment: it is a cloned rendering - but where is it configured where the link custom frame buttons get associated to it ? ie. if I were to duplicate the link folder somewhere, how do I associate those buttons to my rendering on the section selection?

Comment: You can provide a custom (copied and modified) view to your rendering.

Comment: Just to be clear, I've cloned the rendering, I'm using a custom view (cshtml) and custom template.  How would you tie that to a different set of edit frame buttons for the item section?  It's just the edit frame link folder that I'm concerned about which is where I've added a new editor button to.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand. Here is where you are picking up set of edit frame buttons: `@using (Html.Sxa().BeginEditFrame(item.ID.ToString(), "Link", Model.IsControlEditable))`. The "Link" is the name of an item under which the edit frame buttons are stored in the Core database.

Comment: Sorry - brain fade! :)